# Drupal 7 set specific content type on home page

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

**I want to a set specific content type on front page on drupal 7** Only just one content type not all through Programmatically

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to go to `/admin/structure/types` in your site and configure the content type default settings *one by one*, unchecking the `promote to frontpage` setting by default in the non-desired content types.

Also, you can set role-specific permissions in `/admin/people/permissions` so that an specific role (like `site admin` can send any given node to the home page, on a per-node basis, even if it is a node type that is not normally making its way to `<front>`.

Comment: Promote to frontpage only shows in particular post, I want to set my custom content type stories on the homepage. can i do this through programmatically ?

Comment: I want to set stories content type default on home page, because my theme is basically based on stories that's why ..

Comment: Configuring that a certain content type goes *by default* to the homepage is something that can be done in the URLs I pointed above, so you dont need to mark that in every single post, it will be checked by default. Is this what you are looking for?

Answer (score 0):

you can set the front page to a specific node/path at admin/config/system/site-information

If you want a list of specific content types, created a views page and set the front page to the path of this view at the admin page I mention above.